# Validate that minimum value does not exceed the maximum value provided in an Angular app

Tags: javascript, angular, validation, angular-formly, ngx-formly

I have two inputs fields in an angular application, minimum and maximum. I would like to show an error message whenever a user enters a minimum value that is greater than the maximum value, that he/ she provides (or the maximum default value, if they did not provide a value).

My form is within formly.

I have tried to create a custom validator that checks the two form controls and returns an object with the error message - however, the solution doesn't seem to work.

```
function minMaxValidator(c: FormControl) {
  const { min, max } = c.value;

   if (!min || !max) {
     return null;
   }

   if (max >= min) {
     return null;
   }

   return { minMaxValidator: { message: 'Minimum value cannot be more than the maximum value.'}}
}
```

then within my formlyFieldConfig:

```
{
        validators: {
          validation: [
            { name: 'minMaxValidator', options: { errorPath: 'min'}}
          ]
        }
      },
```

My fields are as follows:

```
[
   {
     key: 'min',
     type: 'input',
     templateOptions: {
       label: 'Minimum',
        input: 'number'
     }
   },
 {
     key: 'max',
     type: 'input',
     templateOptions: {
       label: 'Maximum',
       input: 'number'
     }
   }
]
```

Any assistance will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are creating your form controls but here is how I fixed a similar issue
// my form initialization here

```js
  

  this.form = new FormGroup({
      min: new FormControl(null, {validators: [this.validateMinMax()]}),
      max: new FormControl(null),
    });

   //my validation function here
    validateMinMax(): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null => {
      if (this.form === undefined) {
        return null;
      }
      const max = this.form.get('min').value;
      if (control.value !== undefined && control.value >= max) {
          return { confirmPass: true };
      }
      return null;
    };
  }
}
```

you can see inside of validateMinMax() What I am returning is actually a function, not a value. that function then returns the error or null.

another tip. if the user inputs correct min and max values then decide to go back and change the max value into something smaller than the min. you won't get an error.

to fix that you can add a listener on value change on your max input which fires a function like below. that will force your form to recheck all values and fire validators

```js
  updateValidation() {
    this.form.get('max').updateValueAndValidity();
    this.form.get('min').updateValueAndValidity();
  }
```

Hope this helps